# How to get current running ethernet speed from LabWindows\CVI C code or CMD commands

Tags: c, ethernet, labwindows

I am developing Test Equipment which has couple of Ethernet ports. As part of the testing i want to check the current speed of the ethernet ports (10/100/1000) when a tested unit is connected.

How can i get this information? is there a C library or CMD command which i can use that can supply this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `wmic` command like this

`wmic PATH Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE "PhysicalAdapter = TRUE AND NetEnabled = TRUE" GET Name, Speed`

[Win32_NetworkAdapter classof WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to get ONLY the speed for a SPECIFIC ethernet port?

Comment: It matches in the property(e.g `MACAddress`) in the WHERE query.

Answer (score 2):

**C# is probably quicker to get up and running than API access with c/c++.**

Try using the System.Net.NetworkInformation classes.  In particular, [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStatistics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx) ought to have some information along the lines of what you're looking for.

Specifically, you can check the `bytesReceived` property, wait a given interval, and then check the `bytesReceived` property again to get an idea of how many bytes/second your connection is processing.  To get a good number, though, you should try to download a large block of information from a given source, and check then; that way you should be 'maxing' the connection when you do the test, which should give more helpful numbers.

***You need a linux running machine for the code to work
You need to use the `SIOCETHTOOL ioctl()` call in Linux.***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct ethtool_cmd edata;
    int rc;

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
    ifr.ifr_data = &edata;

    edata.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET;

    rc = ioctl(sock, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("ioctl");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch (ethtool_cmd_speed(&edata)) {
        case SPEED_10: printf("10Mbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_100: printf("100Mbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_1000: printf("1Gbps\n"); break;
        default: printf("Speed returned is %d\n", edata.speed);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

I'm not sure about the Windows .May be you can refer here: [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I cant use .net , i am restricted to C

Comment: After changing the signature for main() to `int main( void )` so as to get a clean compile, I ran the code on my linux computer.   It printed `100Mps` which was the correct value.  I did this without trying to 'stuff' the I/O via upload or download of a large file